# Firestore + cloud function: How to tell if it's a create, update, or delete event

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

I want to write a Firebase cloud function that is triggered by a Firestore write event. Inside of the function, I have to know if the write is actually a create, update, or delete function. The logic is slightly different, but I don't want to copy and paste three different event handlers. How can I tell which event type it is?

The cloud documentation reads very confusing to me.

The documentation for Event says that in the case of FireStore, the event is actually a DeltaDocumentSnapshot.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.Event

The documentation for DeltaDocumentSnapshot suggests that the class has no information about the event itself (e.g. indication of create, update, or delete), but only the target document:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.firestore.DeltaDocumentSnapshot

I found samples, where the author seemed to infer create/update/delete by checking if the current or previous document exists. I've tried that but I get an error.

https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/child-count/functions/index.js#L30

Here is what I've tried:

```
exports.updateLikeCount = functions.firestore
.document('likes/{likeId}').onWrite((event) => {
    if (event.data.data().exists()) {
      // Looks like the document still exists. It must be an update or create.
    }

    if (event.data.previous.data().exists()) {
      // Looks like the document existed before. It must be an update or delete.
    }
```

That code fails with this error:

```
TypeError: event.data.exists is not a function
```

Comment: The code you link from `child-count` uses `event.data.exists()`. You've added an extra `data()` in there, which doesn't work.

Answer (score 15):

With the [new release](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff) of firebase-functions version 1.0, a function to check this could look like this (in typescript):

```
import { Change } from 'firebase-functions';

export function checkEventType(change: functions.Change<FirebaseFirestore.DocumentSnapshot>): string {
    const before: boolean = change.before.exists;
    const after: boolean = change.after.exists;

    if (before === false && after === true) {
        return 'create';
    } else if (before === true && after === true) {
        return 'update';
    } else if (before === true && after === false) {
        return 'delete';
    } else {
        throw new Error(`Unkown firestore event! before: '${before}', after: '${after}'`);
    }
}
```

I have tested this function, and works great in combination with the .onWrite() event.

Comment: P.S. The equality checks here are redundant since both values will always be a `boolean`. (It should just be `if (!before && after)` instead of `if (before === false && after === true)`)

Comment: @Edric only true for newer versions of firebase-funcitons. But I would argue that `before === false && after === true` is more easy to understand than `!before && after`. I guess it's just an opinion :)

Comment: i am not sure, how to use this method. can you give any other reference?

Answer (score 2):

I've tried a few different things. The version below seems to work, yet I don't know if it is correct.

```
var exists = event.data.exists;`
var hasExisted = (event.data.previous != null) && event.data.previous.exists;
var isCreate = (exists && !hasExisted);
var isDelete = (!exists && hasExisted);
```